# Increment an iterator standard map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

ALL,

```
std::map<int, std::string> addressee;
std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it1, it2;

for( it1 = addressee.begin(); it1 != addressee().end(); it1++ )
{
    bool found = false;
    for( it2 = it1 + 1; it2 != addressee.end() && !found; it2++ )
    {
       if( it1->second == it1->second )
       {
           printf( "Multiple occurences of addressees found" );
           found = true;
       }
    }
}
```

gcc spits out an error: no match for operator+.

This code is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do right now. I guess I can use std::advance(), but it seems it just going to be a waste of the function call.

Is there a better fix for that?

Comment: "a waste of a function call". A function call is not a "waste".

Comment: `it2 = it1; ++it2;` before the loop and then `for(; it2 != ...)`

Comment: @MooingDuck, no it is not a waste. But it is required some additional operations which I'd rather avoid. And it requires some time to do.

Comment: @Rado, simplest solution. Thank you. I guess I had to look at it from different angle.

Comment: @Igor: What "additional operations" are you imagining? How much "time" do you think it "requires"? Did you measure it? If you did, you'd be surprised. Right now you're just guessing, coming to the wrong conclusions from those guesses, then using those wrong conclusions to arrive at the wrong solution (or, rather, to skip over the right one).

Comment: @Igor: It sounds like you need to unlearn habits from other languages. It is very easy for a C/C++ compiler to do *function inlining* which means that C/C++ does not have *any* of the performance problems you may be used to regarding short, simple operations, unless you do things to defeat function inlining (e.g. dynamic polymorphism with virtual functions). Also, `++it2` is just as much of a function call as `std::advance(it2, 1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::map` does not have random access iterators, only bidirectional iterators, so there's no `+ n` operation. Instead, use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

// ...

for (auto it1 = addressee.begin(), e = addressee.end(); it1 != e; ++it1)
{
    for (auto it2 = std::next(it1); it2 != e; ++it2)
    {
        if (it1->second == it2->second)
        {
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, you should *always* use `std::next`, since it knows which iterator category its argument has and what the most efficient way to compute the next iterator is. That way, you don't have to care about the specific container you happen to be using.

Answer (score 0):

@Kerrek has already pointed out how to handle the problem you're having at the syntactic level.

I'm going to consider the problem at a more algorithmic level--what you're really trying to accomplish overall, rather than just looking at how to repair that particular line of the code.

Unless the collection involved is dependably *tiny* so the efficiency of this operation doesn't matter at all, I'd make a copy of the mapped values from the collection, then use `sort` and `unique` on it to see if there are any duplicates:

```
std::vector<std::string> temp;

std::transform(addressee.begin(), addressee.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(temp),
               [](std::pair<int, std::string> const &in) { return in.second; });

std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());

if (std::unique(temp.begin(), temp.end()) != temp.end()) {
   std::cout << "Multiple occurrences of addressees found";
   found = true;
}
```

This reduces the complexity from O(N<sup>2</sup>) to O(N log N), which will typically be quite substantial if the collection is large at all.

Comment: I would have dropped everything into a `set` or an `unordered_set` myself, inserting things that aren't yet in the set and reporting duplicates for things that already are.

Comment: @Hurkyl: if you *expect* to see quite a few duplicates, that's a reasonable possibility too (but if you're going to insert most items, a vector is generally faster than an an unordered_set, and quite a lot faster than a `set`).