# can I increment an iterator by an integer?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std, stdmap

```
std::map<int, int> m;
// initialize m...
//
int n=3;
for (std::map<int, int>::iterator iter = m.begin()+n; iter != m.end(); ++iter)
// Is the above line correct?
{}
```

Can I increment an iterator by an integer as shown in the code?

Comment: You can't do that with a map iterator [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820047/increment-an-iterator-standard-map). Use std::next

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do "pointer arithmetic" on an iterator only if it is a random access iterator. The iterators of `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, and `std::multimap` are not random access iterators. Supporting the "increment by `n`" operation efficiently for a map iterator would require some extra bookkeeping within the red-black tree structure, which would add overhead for all users. This is a rarely needed operation, so it isn't supported in the standard library.

You can do it the "slow" way with `std::next(m.begin(), n)`. This simply increments a copy of the iterator `n` times and returns the result.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::advance()` or `std::next()` for this:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
...
for (auto iter = next(m.begin(), 3); iter != m.end(); ++iter)
{
}
```

Both `std::advance()` and `std::next()` behave optimally regardless of iterator type.  If you pass a random-access iterator to them, they will use `operator + ()`.  Otherwise, they will repeatedly use `operator ++ ()`.